# How to populate Django databases

Tags: python, django, csrf

What is the preferred way of pre-populating database (Model) objects in a Django app?  I am inclined to try to script POSTing data to the relevant endpoints, but am being stymied by the CSRF protection.

This is not part of the testing framework, this is for setting up demonstration and training instances in a beta testing or production environment.

As a notional example, I'd like to populate the the "Player" database
with three entries: Alice(sender), Bob(reciever) and Charlie(eavesdropper), and I'd like to script/automate the process of creating these entries after deploying and starting the application.

I already have a form based mechanism for creating new Players. By visiting `/create` via a browser, there is a form that allows a person to type in the name, e.g. "Bob" and a role, e.g. "reciever", and submit the form to create the new `Player` instance.

Thus it makes sense to me to try to try to use the existing web API for this: e.g. make calls like
`requests.post('0.0.0.0:8000/create', data={'name':'Bob', 'role':'reciever'})`  in the script that pre-populates the database.  However doing this results in 403 errors due to the CSRF tokens, which I don't want to disable.   This problem also occurs if I just try to use a `requests.Session` to try to maintain the cookies between calls.

One viable solution would involve effectively managing the cookies involved to allow for posting data.  However, I'm open to different ways to allow for creating model instances for initial system configuration.

Relevant code snippets:

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = PlayerForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            s = models.Player()
            s.name = data['name']
            s.role = data['role']
            s.save()
            msg = "TODO: make a senisble return message"
            return HttpResponse(msg)
        else:
            msg = "TODO: make invalid sources message"
            return HttpResponse(msg)

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = PlayerForm()
        return render(request, 'player/create.html', {'target':'/create', 'form': form})



class Player(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=168)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class PlayerForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name:', max_length=168)
    
    role = forms.CharField(label='Role:', max_length=64)
```

Note that the `'target':'/create'` is the target for the form's submit action, i.e. when the user hits "Submit" the data from the form are posted to this endpoint (which then hits the `if request.method == 'POST'` branch to create and save the new instance.

The form is just

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<style>
</style>
<script src=""></script>
<body>

<form action="{{target}}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it were me, I'd enter the bulk data through SQL commands in the command-line tool for whatever database you're using.

Comment: [Fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/initial-data/) are the preferred way of populating the database with initial data.

Comment: @JohnGordon that seems like the right answer.